# Selecting/Forwarding Emails in Outlook based on Subject Criteria (text file)

Tags: email, csv, outlook

Using Outlook 2010 and a .csv text file.

I have a list of ticket numbers that I work with daily. Once I deal with the tickets I have to forward the associated email to a third party. Conveniently, we use unique ticket IDs (6 digit numbers) on all our tickets and I have a program that fills a text file (well, .csv) with the list of the tickets I work every day. I'm trying to find a way to have outlook read that file and search a certain folder for emails with the ticket ID in the subject line and then forward them.

Essentially I want Outlook to read the first line in the .csv, locate the matching Email and forward it. Rinse and Repeat until the file is read all the way through.

Comment: Is this a programming question??

Comment: yes, i'm looking for any ideas on how to write a VB script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming you want to create a VBA macro in Outlook, here's the basic architecture:

- Set a reference to the Microsoft Office Excel Object Model library
- Use [Excel VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff820756%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to open that .csv for editing
- [Search for the emails in Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869846%28v=office.15%29.aspx) using the data you've acquired
  from the spreadsheet

That should get you started!